# When are lambda forms necessary in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, scheme, closures, higher-order-functions

I'm a newbie to Haskell, and a relative newbie to functional programming.
In other (besides Haskell) languages, lambda forms are often very useful.

For example, in Scheme:

```
(define (deriv-approx f)
  (lambda (h x)
    (/ (- (f (+ x h)
          (f x)
       h)))
```

Would create a closure (over the function f) to approximate a derivative (at value x, with interval h).
However, this usage of a lambda form doesn't seem to be necessary in Haskell, due to its partial application:

```
deriv-approx f h x = ( (f (x + h)) - (f x) ) / h
```

What are some examples where lambda forms are necessary in Haskell?

Edit:  replaced 'closure' with 'lambda form'

Comment: I don't think "closure" means what you think it means. It's an implementation technique, not a particular piece of source code. Your Haskell implementation will certainly create a closure for you if you apply your `deriv-approx` partially.

Comment: @Henning There is no certainty that it will create a closure.  As you say, closures are an implementation technique which might or might not be used (it almost always is used).  The same is true for Scheme.

Comment: When you type the explicit version in Haskell, you still get exactly the same code.  Just like some Schemes do if you use `(define ((deriv-approx f) h x) ...)`.

Comment: @Henning The word "closure" has come to mean various different things. I think OP is using it to mean "lambda expression" (which is how it's used in R and possibly Scheme).

Comment: @Owen  yes, that is how I was using it, sorry for any confusion

Comment: @Matt There are situation when you need to return a lambda.  E.g., `f x = let y = something_slow x in \ z -> x + y`.  Written this way, the slow bit will be computed just given the x and then that functions can be reused multiple times.  If you move the z binding to the other side of the let the computation of y will happen on each call.

Comment: @augustss: write that up as a real answer and I'll upvote it; it was the first thing that came to my mind.

Comment: @augustss: Just do `helper x y z = x + y` and `f x = helper x (something_slow x)`. No lambdas!

Comment: @Henning Just because you don't see the lambdas doesn't mean they are not there.  :)  Any function definition is defined to be the same as a lambda, see section 4.4.3.1 of the Haskell report.

Comment: @augustss: Sure. However, as revealed abobe, the OP in this question was not concerned about the structure of the language definition, but was wondering whether the lambda binding _syntax_ is strictly necessary to have.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I really understand the question -- as well as the answers -- a lot better now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm going to give two slightly indirect answers.

First, consider the following code:

```hs
module Lambda where

derivApprox f h x = ( (f (x + h)) - (f x) ) / h
```

I've compiled this while telling GHC to dump an intermediate representation, which is roughly a simplified version of Haskell used as part of the compilation process, to get this:

```hs
Lambda.derivApprox
  :: forall a. GHC.Real.Fractional a => (a -> a) -> a -> a -> a
[LclIdX]
Lambda.derivApprox =
  \ (@ a) ($dFractional :: GHC.Real.Fractional a) ->
    let {
      $dNum :: GHC.Num.Num a
      [LclId]
      $dNum = GHC.Real.$p1Fractional @ a $dFractional } in
    \ (f :: a -> a) (h :: a) (x :: a) ->
      GHC.Real./
        @ a
        $dFractional
        (GHC.Num.- @ a $dNum (f (GHC.Num.+ @ a $dNum x h)) (f x))
        h
```

If you look past the messy annotations and verbosity, you should be able to see that the compiler has *turned everything into lambda expressions*. We can consider this an indication that you probably don't need to do so manually.

Conversely, let's consider a situation where you might need lambdas. Here's a function that uses a fold to compose a list of functions:

```hs
composeAll :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composeAll = foldr (.) id
```

What's that? Not a lambda in sight! In fact, we can go the *other* way, as well:

```hs
composeAll' :: [a -> a] -> a -> a
composeAll' xs x = foldr (\f g x -> f (g x)) id xs x
```

Not only is this full of lambdas, it's also taking two arguments to the main function and, what's more, applying `foldr` to all of them. Compare the type of `foldr`, `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`, to the above; apparently it takes three arguments, but above we've applied it to four! Not to mention that the accumulator function takes *two* arguments, but we have a three argument lambda here. The trick, of course, is that both are returning a function that takes a single argument; and we're simply applying that argument on the spot, instead of juggling lambdas around.

All of which, hopefully, has convinced you that the two forms are equivalent. Lambda forms are never necessary, or perhaps always necessary, because who can tell the difference?

Answer (score 6):

There is no semantic difference between

```
f x y z w = ...
```

and

```
f x y = \z w -> ...
```

The main difference between expression style (explicit lambdas) and declaration style is a syntactic one. One situation where it matters is when you want to use a `where` clause:

```hs
f x y = \z w -> ...
   where ... -- x and y are in scope, z and w are not
```

It is indeed possible to write any Haskell program without using an explicit lambda anywhere by replacing them with named local functions or partial application.

See also: [Declaration vs. expression style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Declaration_vs._expression_style).

Comment: Those leaning toward a lambda-less lifestyle might also like to avail themselves of the `pointfree` program, additionally available as lambdabot's `@pl` command on IRC, to easily enhance the elegance of their expressions.

Comment: @C. A. McCann And then make some of them incomprehensible to normal humans ;)

Answer (score 3):

When you can declare named curried functions (such as your Haskell `deriv-approx`) it is never *necessary* to use an explicit lambda expression. Every explicit lambda expression can be replaced with a partial application of a named function that takes the free variables of the lambda expression as its first parameters.

Why one would want to do this in source code is not easy to see, but some implementations essentially work that way.

Also, somewhat beside the point, would the following rewriting (different from what I've just described) count as avoiding lambdas for you?

```
deriv-approx f = let myfunc h x = (f(x+h)-(f x))/h in myfunc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only use a function once, e.g. as a parameter to map or foldr or some other higher-order function, then it is often better to use a lambda than a named function, because it immediately becomes clear that the function isn't used anywhere else - it can't be, because it doesn't have a name. When you introduce a new named function, you give people reading your code another thing to remember for the duration of the scope. So lambdas are never strictly speaking *necessary*, but they are often preferable to the alternative.

Comment: On the other hand, by giving it a name, you have a chance to explain to the reader what it does, if it's not obvious from just looking at it.